# How can you remove markings from a headset?

Tags: headset

I'm trying to remove logos and markings from a headset, but I think they're laser etched. Does anyone know if it's possible to remove them?

Comment: It would likely require some sort of abrasive polishing.  And if the parts are aluminum you could damage them.

Comment: What's your goal in doing this ?  Trying to make the bike look plainer because you don't like decals ?   Or trying to hide the origins of a part?

Comment: I don't know why, but the idea of removing original markings smells fishy to me. Why should one do that?

Comment: @Carel People remove all markings so that the next owner can post a question on Stack Exchange asking what kind of bike it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item is laser-etched there will be a slight recess in the material.  Nothing will remove that short of filling it in with autobody fill/bog, sanding smooth, and then painting the whole thing.

You could make it more discreet by simply painting the part with spraypaint, the same colour it already is.

If the logo is a decal you can use very gentle heat to soften the adhesive and then acetone or any goo-removing product to melt the adhesive.

Another simple option is to cover that part with something useful, like a headlight or a bike computer/headunit.

Is too late, but you could also prefer to buy parts that don't have the logos in the first place.